# Any jquery autocomplete plugin which consumes this json format?

Tags: jquery, json, autocomplete

Any jquery autocomplete plugin which consumes this json format?

```
{"Table" : [{"ClientName" : "Pandiya"},
{"ClientName" : "Bala"}]}
```

or how to change the above to

```
source: ["Pandiya", "Bala"]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be very easy to handle this with the [jQuery UI autocomplete plugin](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/):

```
var list = {"Table" : [{"ClientName" : "Pandiya"},{"ClientName" : "Bala"}]};
$("#autcomplete").autocomplete({
    source: $.map(list.Table, function(item) {
                return {
                    label: item.ClientName,
                    value: item.ClientName
                }
            })
});
```

Comment: there will be no url.... Just the json data alone... Please see my edit... I need to change json string to that format..

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, [the one in jQuery UI](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Autocomplete) lets you define a custom callback, in which you can do any filtering and transforms you like on the results, and convert your results to the format the widget likes.

Comment: i dont want a call back function... I want my plugin to just come that json data...

Comment: ...why not? Do you really think it'd be a good idea to create separate jQuery plugins for each and every data format there is? A callback function is the most flexible way.

Comment: i agree with you, i did it with yui but not with jquery?

Comment: @Pandiya Chendur: I... have no idea what that is supposed to mean